# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property foo of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

My JavaScript:

```
todo.completed = !todo.completed;
```

ERROR:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'completed' of undefined
    at Object.toggleCompleted (script.js:34)
    at Object.toggleCompleted (script.js:89)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):33)
toggleCompleted @ script.js:34
toggleCompleted @ script.js:89
onclick @ (index):33
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: have you declared `todo`, like `var todo = {}`

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory.  What about it is confusing you?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't declared the variable todo yet.  Try something like `todo = {};`  Let me know if you have questions!

Answer (score 0):

The variable `todo` has passed out of *scope*. It's probably declared in a function that is outside the closure of `handlers.toggleCompleted()` when it is called.

There are a couple of ways to fix this, but as the simplest you can just make `todo` global:

1. Find `var todo` and remove `var` from the start.
2. At the top of your JS add `var todo = {};`

This will make `todo` a global object that's always defined on your page.

Comment: @mb432 This may well work for you but it is a bad habit to get into. If you use it now to get started put a big mental note in place to learn better ways of handling this than this idea. You need to look into namespaces and other options to make this a safer and more sustainable solution. But, for now, if it works, then use it. Don't let perfection be the enemy of good enough.

Comment: @jwpfox yes, entirely, all that. You're talking best practice when the OP doesn't understand scopes and closures. Sticking a global var in is a crappy way to solve this problem, but it's the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

What's so confusing about it is that the code will work in Plunkr, glitch or codepen, but not a text editor and browser, because of the way those sites's routing is set up. In your index.html file you need to replace      `<script src = "filename.js></script>`
 with
 `<script src="entire path to filename.js"></script>`